# Use xsl:analyze-string and preserve markup (like in an identity transform)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I would like to process an XML file so that whatever stands before or after two newlines in a row gets turned into a paragraph (like in LaTeX).

This is the source file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE letter SYSTEM "../Schema_and_DTD/entities.dtd">
<letter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../Schema_and_DTD/letter.xsd" page_id="940"title="1695-08-17_Faeh_Georg-Bernoulli_Johann_I" catalogue_id="000055848">

<facsimile src=""/> Colendissime ac ornatissime Domine etc.

Colendissimae dominationi Vestrae gratificandi ergo, exactissima diligentia tum in Bibliotheca nostra Conventuali, tum in Bibliopolio mihi commisso perquisivi Chronicon Joannis Vitodurani<ref><i>Die Chronik Johanns von Winterthur (Chronica Iohannis Vitodurani)</i>, herausgegeben von F. Baethgen und C. Brun in: <i>Scriptores rerum Germanicarum</i>, Nova series 3, Berlin 1924.</ref>, sed nihil de eo repertum fuit.<ref>Leibniz hat die Chronik des Johannes von Winterthur später aus Bremen erhalten und in seinem <i>Codex juris gentium diplomaticus</i>, Hanoverae 1693, abgedruckt.</ref> Hisce post mei recommendationem omnem prosperitatem a Bono Deo intime apprecans sum et ero Ornatissimae vestrae dominationis Addictissimus servus P. Georgius Fäch.

Ex Eremo B. V. M.<ref>Einsiedeln</ref> 17. Augusti Anno 1695.

</letter>
```

I found this solution: [XSLT - add <p> into text strings instead of \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671444/xslt-add-p-into-text-strings-instead-of-n)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="letter">

    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="&#xa;&#xa;">
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <p>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
                </p>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>

</xsl:template>
```

This comes already close to what I want but the problem is that `<xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />` does not preserve any of the markup. In the end, I just have paragraph-tags containing the textual contents (all the tags got removed).

I thought of an identity transform but I am not allowed to use `<xsl:apply-templates />` instead of `<xsl:value-of select=".">`.

What I want to produce is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE letter SYSTEM "../Schema_and_DTD/entities.dtd">
<letter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../Schema_and_DTD/letter.xsd" page_id="940" title="1695-08-17_Faeh_Georg-Bernoulli_Johann_I" catalogue_id="000055848">

<p><facsimile src=""/> Colendissime ac ornatissime Domine etc.</p>

<p>Colendissimae dominationi Vestrae gratificandi ergo, exactissima diligentia tum in Bibliotheca nostra Conventuali, tum in Bibliopolio mihi commisso perquisivi Chronicon Joannis Vitodurani<ref><i>Die Chronik Johanns von Winterthur (Chronica Iohannis Vitodurani)</i>, herausgegeben von F. Baethgen und C. Brun in: <i>Scriptores rerum Germanicarum</i>, Nova series 3, Berlin 1924.</ref>, sed nihil de eo repertum fuit.<ref>Leibniz hat die Chronik des Johannes von Winterthur später aus Bremen erhalten und in seinem <i>Codex juris gentium diplomaticus</i>, Hanoverae 1693, abgedruckt.</ref> Hisce post mei recommendationem omnem prosperitatem a Bono Deo intime apprecans sum et ero Ornatissimae vestrae dominationis Addictissimus servus P. Georgius Fäch.</p>

<p>Ex Eremo B. V. M.<ref>Einsiedeln</ref> 17. Augusti Anno 1695.</p>

</letter>
```

Is there a way to get the whole non-matching substring (including markup) and just wrap it with paragraph tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need two passes, one that inserts a certain element (I have choosen `br` but of course you can choose anything that does not interfere with your existing vocabulary), and a second that uses `for-each-group` `group-starting-with="br"`:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="letter">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:variable name="letter-with-line-breaks">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="breaks"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="$letter-with-line-breaks/letter/node()" group-starting-with="br">
                <p>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[not(self::br)]"/>
                </p>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="letter//text()" mode="breaks">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="&#10;&#10;">
          <xsl:matching-substring>
              <br/>
          </xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:non-matching-substring>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

That should give you an idea, I think you need some white space tuning.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that!

Comment: I actually expect paragraphs only als direct children of <letter>. Should it say: <xsl:template match="letter/text()" mode="breaks"> instead?

Comment: Yes, I think `<xsl:template match="letter/text()" mode="breaks">` suffices if you are only interested in the line breaks in children of `letter` elements and I think my current grouping suggestion is also only geared towards that scenario so change the patter to `match="letter/text()" mode="breaks"`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches to this problem.

One is to add markup to the text, and then use facilities like grouping to process the structure indicated by the markup: that's the approach Martin is using.

The second approach is to convert the existing markup to textual annotation of some kind, then use analyze-string to manipulate the text, and then convert the textual annotation back to markup.

With XSLT 3.0, the second approach can be achieved by serializing the content of the `<p>` element to a string (using `fn:serialize()`), then applying `xsl:analyze-string`, then parsing the results back to nodes in a tree  using `fn:parse-xml()`.